# Layout for admins and users Login page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, devise

I have **admin user authentication** with devise
I generated devise for user and one for admin
and i am making layout using main devise layout page
here is my route file

```
devise_for :admins

devise_scope :admin do
  get '/admins/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
  authenticated :admin do
    root 'home#index'
  end
  #  delete "/logout" => "devise/sessions#destroy"
end

devise_for :users

devise_scope :user do
  get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
  authenticated :user do
    root 'user_home#index', as: :authenticated_root
  end

  unauthenticated do
    root 'devise/sessions#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
  end
end
```

I want to differentiate between the title of the admin page and the user page login.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use cancancan gem or pundit gem for role management. 
Example for cancancan:

```
<% if current_user.has_role? :admin %>
 // something...
<% else %>
 // other...
<% end %>
```

Comment: layout :layout_by_resource
  protected

def layout_by_resource
  if devise_controller? && resource_name == :user
    "userlayout"
  elsif devise_controller? && resource_name == :admin
    "devise"
  else
    "application"

  end

Comment: It may not be a good idea, They all belongs_to user but has different role and permission, you can diff them in controllers.